# Replace function pointers by templates in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a script (python symbolic toolbox) which auto-generates C++11 code to fill the entries of a matrix, like:

```
double J00(double a, double b) {return a+b;}
double J01(double a, double b) {return a-b;}
double J10(double a, double b) {return -a+b;}
double J11(double a, double b) {return -a-b;}
```

Now I could use an array of function pointers to store all the functions and fill the matrix, i.e.:

```
typedef double  (*FillFunction) (double a, double b);

double J00(double a, double b) {return a+b;}
double J01(double a, double b) {return a-b;}
double J10(double a, double b) {return -a+b;}
double J11(double a, double b) {return -a-b;}

void main()
{
    FillFunction J[2][2] = {{J00, J01}, {J10, J11}};

    param0 = 0;
    param1 = 1;

    double Jresult[2][2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            Jresult[i][j] = J[i][j](param0, param1);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is a performance critical part of my code and I would thus rather not use function pointers, especially since the size of the matrix and all functions are know at compile time. Is there a neat way to do this with templates or anything similar?

Note: I did not compile this code so I don't know if it would actually work, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: With C++14, you may simply create `constexpr` function.

Comment: Can you use `std::array<std::array<int, 2u>, 2u>` instead of C-array ?

Comment: Why not generate *once* function that fills in the whole matrix?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have C++1 available. Wouldn't the std::array approach get evaluated at runtime as well? Maybe I just don't know what you mean by "2u"

Comment: Generating one function that fills the matrix is probably the best solution. I guess I am just to tired tonight to see such a simple solution ;). Thanks!

Comment: It may help the optimizer to make that array `static const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using external code generator anyway, just generate this:

```
double Jresult[2][2] = {
    {J00(param0, param1), J01(param0, param1)},
    {J10(param0, param1), J11(param0, param1)},
};
```